# Sencha Touch SegmentedButton setPressed not working?

Tags: sencha-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm making an iPhone app, I've got a simple segmented button in sencha touch and when I click  a reset button in my settings form I want the segmented button to change the pressed button to default.
I've got something like this:
view:

```
var typPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: {type: 'hbox', pack: 'center'},
    items: {
        xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
        id: 'dumbyt',
        items: [
            { 
                text: 'Dum'
            },
            { 
                text: 'Byt',
                pressed: true
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

in the reset button controller i've got

```
setdefault: function(options) {
    ...
    realio.views.settingsPanel.getComponent('dumbyt').setPressed(0);
}
```

I also tried assigning id to each button and call .setPressed('id'); but it didn't work too, any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it with just Ext.getComponent('dumbyt').setPressed(0); ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the arguments for setPressed:
[Link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/)